# php artisan serve not working with different ports

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-artisan

When I type in

```
php artisan serve --host test.com
```

I got this error

> [Wed Jan 14 12:54:12 2015] Failed to listen on test.com:8000 (reason: Can't assign requested address)

so I tried

```
php artisan serve --host test.com --port 8080
```

and I still got the same error just the port number is different. And it's the same with every number I can think of.

Comment: and what about port 80? you are using Linux/Windows/Mac?

Comment: Why are you not binding to localhost? I'm pretty sure that development server should not be used to bind to any other address.

Comment: @violator667 - I'm using a mac and I can't use port 80, because that is being used by apache

Comment: @Franz - I'm trying to do something so I want to mimic a live server and that is what php artisan serve kind of does. So I need a "domain" name. Even though at the moment it's a fake one

Comment: But why not just bind to an unused port on localhost?

Comment: @Franz - That is what I've tried to do. In my terminal I typed in `sudo lsof -i :5000` and nothing appeared only a new line to type in. So I tried `php artisan serve --host test.com --port 5000` and I got the same error again

Comment: `php artisan serve --host localhost --port 5000`

Comment: or add 'test.com' to your `/private/etc/hosts` (I think that's right for Macs) to locally give that address the IP of localhost: `127.0.0.1`.  and then run your serve command with the same options

Comment: @Franz - that worked. How is it that the one you gave me worked and the one I tried didn't?

Comment: @Niks Yours did not work because you used another domain, that either did not resolve via DNS, or did to another computer. Thus, PHP didn't know how to bind to the IP address of that computer. With `localhost`, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to assign a port on another server, to get around this you can either add that domain into your "hosts" file, or use a port on localhost.

### 1. **Add to "hosts" file**

On most linux distributions it's here: `/etc/hosts` and on mac: `/private/etc/hosts`.

You should add a new line following the format of the other lines in the file.  Assign the IP of localhost (127.0.0.1) to that domain like so:

```
127.0.0.1       test.com
```

Now you will be able to open ports on localhost, using test.com:

```
php artisan serve --host test.com --port 8080
```

...and now you can access your app, in your browser via: `http://test.com:8080`.

### 2. **Use localhost**

Alternatively just assign a port on locahost:

```
php artisan serve --host localhost --port 5000
```

and access in your browser via: `http://localhost:5000`

Answer (score 0):

sometimes your IP address get changed so first go to command prompt and type ipconfig there **ipv4** address will be listed copy it and the go to terminal type php **artisan serve --host youripaddress**. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use php artisan serve --port='YOUR-PORT' command.

or

you can create a variable SERVER_PORT in your .env file

Example:

```
SERVER_PORT=80
```